# Книга по Ruby on Rails 3.2.9 с примерами

Tags: книги, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте уважаемые. Я только начал изучать RoR и уже напоролся на "риф". Читаю книгу Agile Web Development with Rails (Fourth edition) 2010 года, но в ней все примеры на Ruby 1.8.7 + RoR 3.0.1, я попытался все настроить в RVM, установил параллельно еще одну версию Ruby (основная стоит 1.9.3), создал новый gemset для этой версии, потом попытался установить нужную версию RoR (3.0.1), но установилась версия 3.2.9.

Теперь я прошу помощи у Вас, дорогие знатоки, потому что выучить RoR нужно в самые короткие сроки.
Заранее Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не привязывайся сильно к старым версиям, почти всё работает также. Ставь 1.9.3 и 3.2.9 и не мучайся. Советую взять ещё какую-нибудь книгу и читать параллельно.

Comment: Спасибо за совет, может быть Вы мне еще и книжку посоветуете по этой версии RoR (можно и на английском языке), а то я не находил.

Comment: Я занимался по "Beginning Rails 3", а потом http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ и http://api.rubyonrails.org/

Answer (score 0):

[rusrails.ru](http://rusrails.ru)

> На этом сайте выложены переводы официального руководства по `Rails`. Надеемся, это руководство позволит вам немедленно приступить к использованию `Rails` и поможет разобраться, что и как там работает.

Answer (score 0):

Если знания английского позволяют [то можно попробовать](http://www.codecademy.com/#!/exercises/0)